# How to make django channels group_send() send to everyone connected after a time.sleep() delay?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a consumers.py class method that sends a message to everyone in the channels group with group_send(), and it works great. My issue is that I have a separate, independent class method where I want to call group_send(), then time.sleep(), then group_send() again. For example:

```
self.returnState()
time.sleep(5)
self.returnState()
```

It's working (kind of) right now, but the issue is that it sends the message to everyone in the group EXCEPT the person who initially triggered the event (sent a message from the front end to consumers.py).

I have no idea why this would be happening, as I would expect that if group_send() was triggered and the message was sent to one person in the group immediately, it should be sent to all. I understand asyncio.sleep() might be a more robust solution, but that would require me changing my entire consumers.py class to async.

I'm very lost and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might it be that the message is only sent to the user after this function completes? The websocket connection is being handled by a function that is currently sleeping?

Comment: That's what it seems like. I guess I just don't understand why exactly that's the case, and if there's a way to get around it without async methods.